# What are some uses of local iterator for STL unordered containers?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, unordered-set, unordered-multimap, unordered-multiset

In *§23.2.7 Unordered associative containers [unord.req]* of the C++ standard *table 91* describes the additional requirements a STL unordered associative container must meet. In this table the standard dictates that the STL unordered containers (i.e., [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set), [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), [`unordered_multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset) and [`unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)) must provide as member types `local_iterator` and `const_local_iterator`.

[image]

- [`local_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)  is an iterator type whose category, value, difference, pointer and
  reference types are the same as the unordered container's `iterator`. This iterator can be used to iterate through a single bucket but not across buckets.
- [`const_local_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) is an iterator type whose category, value, difference, pointer and reference types are the same as the unordered container's `const_iterator`. This iterator can be used to iterate through a single bucket but not across buckets.

### Q

What are some uses for these iterators?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main thing I can see it being used for is to check how many collisions you have.  Using [`bucket`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket) you can get what bucket a key is stored in.  You can then pass that bucket value to [`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/begin2) which will return a `local_iterator` to the items in that bucket.  Now you can iterate that bucket and see if you collide with any other elements and if you do, what those elements are.  This, in turn, allows you to tune your hashing function.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is quite useful, when you want to efficiently get a random element from an `unordered_map`.

With a `vector`, we can generate a random index, and get a random elements with that index in O(1). However, this does work with an `unordered_map`.

Instead, we can generate a random *bucket* index, and call `unordered_map::begin(index)` to get a random bucket in O(1). Then we can generate a random *local* index, i.e. index of elements in the bucket, and iterate elements with the `local_iterator` to get a random element (this step is NOT O(1), however, normally number of elements in a bucket is small).

```
unordered_map<int, int>::const_local_iterator random_element(const unordered_map<int, int> &m) {
    if (m.bucket_count() == 0)
        throw runtime_error("empty map");
    while (true) {
        auto bucket_index = gen_random_num() % m.bucket_count();
        auto bucket_size = m.bucket_size(bucket_index);
        if (bucket_size == 0)
            continue;
        auto element_index = gen_random_num() % bucket_size;
        return std::next(m.cbegin(bucket_index), element_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn’t that bias the distribution towards elements in less-populated buckets?

Comment: Yes. So this method depends on a good hash function evenly distributing keys in buckets.

Comment: Even the best hash function won’t reliably do that.