See hash distribution of std::unordered_map in C++
What is the best way to see how well my hash function is working in an unordered_map in C++? I am using Visual Studio 2022 and in the debugger there is no easy way of seeing the distribution within the map as the Natvis configuration does not support the internal buckets.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42226894/4342498

The std::unordered_map interface provides the member functions bucket_count and bucket_size.
By iterating over all buckets calling bucket_size you can retrieve the exact current distribution.
